# Android view flipping vs. Activity ending

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, textview

I have this [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.timeactive.memory&hl=en). It displays random numbers for an interval of time.

Right now, I am ending the main activity that displays the numbers and restarting it through a thread. One issue I have had with this is that newer phones run an animation between activities, and I don't want that animation to run. Are there any other issues with this approach?

Instead of having the activity restart every 5 seconds, I tried to have the textview reset the text within the thread, but this force closes the application. I don't know why it does this, but my guess is that the thread is running separately from the activity and I cannot reference anything from the activity in my thread. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how restarting works with respect to animations, but maybe [`overridePendingTransition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)) could be helpful?

On the other hand, it does seem odd to be restarting an Activity every 5 seconds. Updating the TextView seems a more light-weight way to achieve the same effect. What does the stack trace say when the application crashes when attempting to update the TextView?

Comment: I referenced the wrong textview from my xml, but now the question becomes, how do you restart a thread after it ends, but that's probably answered already somewhere else. I will look into overridePendingTransition, before I make any major changes. Thanks!